# PHP session errors after transfer from local development server to production server

Tags: php, session

It appears there are inconsistencies with my sessions when I upload my website to the production server. All works accordingly on my development machine but my sessions cease to work as desired on the production server. I have tried uploading to a different server and it works well meaning that there is no problem with the code.

The sessions are useful in redirecting users to previous pages they came from using headers as well as storing and outputting total number of items in the shopping cart array.

What are the common inconsitencies experienced with sessions or headers when php files are moved from local development to production servers and how can I fix it?

Here is a sample of my code.

```
//=========================================================================
//SECTION 1: Add items to cart
//=========================================================================
if((isset($_POST["submit-checkout"])) OR (isset($_POST["submit-continue"]))) {
    //Posted variables
    $freight = $_POST["freight"];
    $order_quantity = $_POST["order_quantity"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $weight = $_POST["weight"];
    $minimum = $_POST["minimum"];
    $product_name= $_POST["product_name"];
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $url = "".$_SESSION["return_to_page"]."";
    //Check for order quantity and redirect if it's less than minimum acceptable value
    if($order_quantity < $minimum) {
        $_SESSION["error"] = $product_name;
        redirect_to("$url");
    }       
    //Set url to redirect user based on whether they want to check out or to keep shopping for more products
    if(isset($_POST["submit-checkout"])) {
        $url ="cart.php";
    } else {
        $url = "".$_SESSION["return_to_page"]."";
    }
    addtocart($url, $order_quantity, $type, $weight, $product_name, $id, $price, $freight);
}
```

Comment: for session, you should start it before using it and header for redirecting purpose you could not use the echo statement before the header, check your files for session_start();

Comment: @sudhakar I have started sessions in all pages and didn't echo anything before the redirect function was called. The code works on other servers, just not on the production server.

Comment: Another thing, from php.ini session can be auto started. If it is done in your production server, then it will be a problem. If you start session in your code it will cause an error. so best practice to start session is if(!session_id()) session_start(); It will start session if session is not started already other wise undone

Comment: @Salim tried that, doesn't seem to be working. It won't even add items in the cart in some instances, but it works flawlessly in local development.

Comment: Did you look through all of these options carefully? http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php Are PHP versions the same? I can't think of anything else, sorry.

Comment: @Ariane tried updating my settings to various versions to no avail. let me go through these config settings one by one.

Comment: If you're using a hosting service that provides service, perhaps you can call them and ask them what's wrong. There's always a chance that only they have the answer, or have an easy way of finding it.